# Find the Hahn Banach extension of a operator in $L_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $H=L_2 [0,1]$ and $G=\{f \in L_2[0,1] : \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=0\}$. Find the Hahn - Banach extension of the functional $L:G \rightarrow H$ defined as
$$L(f)=\int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x)dx$$

In the proof of the Hahn - Banach theorem, we obtain some possible interval of values of the extension, but I don't know how to use this fact. Then I tried to explore the set $G$ for a certain property but I couldn't find anything.

I will be grateful for any hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is a closed subspace  of a Hilbert space $H$ and $g$ is a  continuous linear funnctional on $G$ then the Hahn Banach extension  $h$ of $g$ is given by $h(x+y)=g(x)$ where $x \in M$ and $y \in M^{\perp}$. In other words $h$ is $0$ on $M^{\perp}$.

In this case $M^{\perp}= \{cx: c \in F\}$. ($F$ being the scalar field). Can you write down the extension explicitly using these facts?  [Any $f$ can be decomopsed as $cx +(f(x)-cx)$ where $c=2\int_0^{1} tf(t)dt$. This makes $f(x)-cx \in M^{\perp}$].

Comment: ohhh i see, Thanks!!